# Badge Hammer - How To Use Responsibly?

Tags: discussion

With great power comes great responsibility. I recently joined the gold `[apex]` badge club, and I just wonder what sort of changes I need to make to my `Close Vote` strategy. I have read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders), but it's still a little unclear to me. Does it affect any type of `Close Vote` or `Reopen Vote` besides duplicates? Can you vote to close and reopen the same question once each?

Anyway, this discussion might also serve to remind/explain to the [rest of the club](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) what increased responsibilities are involved. Thanks!

Comment: Those stats on the badges are very interesting, particularly when you look at all-time rankings on each tag to compare points with questions answered. Oh, and good question. Will be a long time before I'll need to be concerned with the answer though. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tend to go in like Thor with Mjölnir and then pick up the pieces later.

[image]

Mostly I just double check the tags looking for the ones that would cause me to immediately close it. I thought they usually showed up with a gold mark next to them on the question, but I'm not seeing it currently.

Generally, if you still think the question should be closed/reopened, follow the same procedure you usually would. If the question could be refined, I usually prefer an edit or comment to start with.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to comment and a lot of the time leave the response up to the community. I like to get a feel for what others think but as a moderator if I click "vote to close" on anything it gets smashed straight away.