# Is there a way to choose if you use the Badge Hammer or not

Tags: feature-request, exact-duplicates, review-queue

Having the badge hammer is a bit of a double edge sword. There are times when you may *think* a question has a duplicate but are not sure. Especially during review...

It would be nice if there was an option to apply the badge hammer or let op/community decide on status of duplicate yet still be able to mark it as duplicate and place it in the queue.

As it stands I believe the only thing one can do is add a comment and not place the question in the queue.

Am I correct in this assumption or is there a way to do it without bringing the hammer down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Once you have it, that is the only <s>hammer</s>vote you can swing. I'm in the same boat as a moderator, now every close vote is binding, so I am much less likely to vote in general. With great power...yada yada.

You might also find this question interesting: [Badge Hammer - How To Use Responsibly?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2183/badge-hammer-how-to-use-responsibly)

[image: Mjolnir][1]

Comment: Thanks, I saw that answer but was hoping tagging this as a feature request may well work as a feature request lol....Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: I'll ask around.

Comment: Seems like this is a commonly requested feature and there's a lot of pushback. In other words, don't hold your breath. @Eric

Comment: Ha, reminds me of another process, what was it, ahh, Salesforce Ideas lol